# Eclipse not recognizing imports in same project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-classpath

From time to time, `Eclipse` (Indigo) complains that certain classes in my projects `cannot be resolved to a type`. Even it shows the class in popup list, clicking `import` (see image) does not add the import statement! Even if I add it manually, it doesn't recognize it (and underlines the import package).

- This happens only in certain projects.
- Unresolved types are in the same project! (not in other dependencies)
- cleaning the project does resolve this, but only temporarily.
- My application consists of multi-module maven based projects.
- All projects are maven-based.

[Not recognizing imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Vy7.png)

Comment: Indigo was released in 2011. Consider using latest version.

Comment: Do not forget to hide package name in class DefinitionMappings if necessary.

Comment: @Valijon thanks. done.

Comment: This happened to me all of a sudden, on the latest version so I think this is a valid question.

Comment: @AleksandrM Do I need to recreate this post for asking the same question, even though I'm running into the same problem?

Answer (score 9):

Right click on your project name ->Maven ->Update Project

Comment: I think you should try the latest version of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For those not using Maven, simply deleting the project (and possibly re-cloning it) has reliably worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to be in Eclipse Neon.2 (2016 release) on a non-Maven project. Refreshing / updating the project did not help, but I was able to fix this without recreating the project:

1. Go to Properties → Build Path → Source
2. Remove all source folders in the build path, click Apply.
3. Add them all back, click Apply.

Comment: interestingly in my gradle project set up removing and adding them causes the issues to flicker on screen like it sees them then they vanish from sight again. very frustrating but did not help me

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Maven -> Update Project...

Check (Force Update of Snapshots/Releases)